# How to make images same size and responsive

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I edited my photos so they all are the same height and the canvas size is the same height, but they come out looking uneven.  How can I make them look all the same size on the page and still be responsive when I change the browser window size?

[This is what my page looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsJhg.png)

This is my HTML

```
<div class="row">

<!-- 3 Articles -->

<section>
    <article class="col-4 col-m-4">
        <h4>Cosmetics</h4>
        <div class="img-box">
            <img src="images/powder.png">
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    </article>

    <article class="col-4 col-m-4">
        <h4>Bath &amp; Shower</h4>
        <div class="img-box">
            <img src="images/radiumbath.png">
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </article>

    <article class="col-4 col-m-4">
        <h4>Health &amp; Wellness</h4>
        <div class="img-box">
            <img src="images/waterbottle.png">
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </article>
</section>

</div>
```

This is img CSS and responsive grid:

```
img {

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}

/* RESPONSIVE */

/* MOBILE */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}

/* TABLET */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}

/* DESKTOP */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
```

Comment: This is because although the heights of the images are the same, their widths are different.

Comment: @Ashonko If I do this: img{ width:auto; height:100%;}  then they are the same size but they don't scale when I shrink the browser window.

Comment: try `max-height: 100%;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the images a `max-width`

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/19294/)

You just need to make sure the smallest image is bigger than the max-width, otherwise it won't change and make sure the resolution is the same.

If the images were in different resolutions, (16:9, 4:3 etc.) you have to crop the images beforehand or implement some js shenanigans.